# Segmentation fault when using a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

It appears that getting segmentation faults when using a vector is a common issue, however I still can't seem to resolve my issue.  It is not clear to me why the vector in the getArmPose function code segment is causing a segmentation fault.

```
class CytonServer
{
public:
    CytonServer();
private:
    std::vector <double> arm_pos_;
....


    void CytonServer::publish_Callback()
    { 
     ROS_INFO("PUBLISH");
      boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(publish_mutex_);
      if (teleop_vehicle_==false)
      {
         ROS_INFO("Publishing ");
         end_effector_type = "point_end_effector"; 

         //Here is the culprip see function below
         arm_pos_ = cytonCommands.getArmPose();
         .....
       }
    }

//In a different file is the following method that is called and is causing the segmentation fault


std::vector <double> EcCytonCommands::getArmPose()
{

  double x,y,z;
  std::vector<double> arm_pos_;
    EcManipulatorEndEffectorPlacement actualEEPlacement;
    EcCoordinateSystemTransformation actualCoord;

    getActualPlacement(actualEEPlacement);
    actualCoord=actualEEPlacement.offsetTransformations()[0].coordSysXForm();

    arm_pos_.push_back(actualCoord.translation().x());
    arm_pos_.push_back(actualCoord.translation().y());

    arm_pos_.push_back(actualCoord.translation().z());

    return arm_pos_;
}
```

Any assistance on how to resolve this issues will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like the vector should be causing any issues from this example. Try replacing the stuff in getArmPose() to not do any queries and just push_back() some testing values. See whether it still segfaults in that function.

Comment: can you be more specific as to where the segfault happens? Use a tool like valgrind, it is a great tool to detect memory leaks, segfaults, uninitialized values etc.

Comment: vector segfaults almost always come from reading from an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: don't use `std::vector<>` for shipping 3 doubles. Since the number is known at compile time (and the objects are trivial), better use `std::array`.

Comment: What are the function signatures of translation() and x()?

Comment: Does `EcCytonCommands` reside in a shared library?

Comment: Could you please tell us what makes you think the segfault is due to the code inside `EcCytonCommands::getArmPose()` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the quick feedback. We have discovered that the issue was not with the vectors but instead the 3rd party app I was calling was not thread safe.  Adding a mutex lock has resolved the issue.

```
std::vector <double> EcCytonCommands::getArmPose()
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(publish_mutex_);
  std::vector<double> arm_pos_;

    EcManipulatorEndEffectorPlacement actualEEPlacement;
    EcCoordinateSystemTransformation actualCoord;

    getActualPlacement(actualEEPlacement);
    actualCoord=actualEEPlacement.offsetTransformations()[0].coordSysXForm();

    arm_pos_.push_back(actualCoord.translation().x());
    arm_pos_.push_back(actualCoord.translation().y());

    arm_pos_.push_back(actualCoord.translation().z());

    std::cout << "size, x, y, z: " <<arm_pos_.size()<< " "<<arm_pos_[0] <<", "<<arm_pos_[1]<<", "<<arm_pos_[2] <<std::endl;
}
```